# How to clear username and password on CocoaLibSpotify logout?

Tags: objective-c, ios, spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0

I'm using the `CocoaLibSpotify` library to develop an iOS application that will utilize the Spotify API. I've got it just about where I want it, but I've run into a bit of a problem.

When the user touches my "Logout of Spotify" button, I execute the following code:

```
-(IBAction)logoutButtonTouched:(id)sender
{
    // Clear out the user's settings that I am saving.
    NSString *appDomain = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:appDomain];

    [[SPSession sharedSession] logout:^(void) {
        SPLoginViewController *controller = [SPLoginViewController loginControllerForSession:[SPSession sharedSession]];
        controller.allowsCancel = NO;
    }];
}
```

This does indeed logout the user and display the `SPLoginViewController`, but my problem is, the username and password field still contain the values that they'd logged-in with. Does anyone know of a way to clear these fields when I display the `SPLoginViewController`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality isn't in the login controller, which is indeed a bug.

You can do it like this. Please note that this is really fragile code and will fail if any internal detail of the login controller changes, and it *will* in the future:

```
SPLoginViewController *controller = [SPLoginViewController loginControllerForSession:[SPSession sharedSession]];

id internalLoginViewController = [controller.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
UITextField *loginField = [internalLoginViewController valueForKey:@"usernameField"];
UITextField *passwordField = [internalLoginViewController valueForKey:@"passwordField"];
loginField.text = @"";
passwordField.text = @"";
```

Comment: Thanks! That'll certainly do for now!